# Update from old Kubuntu 18.10 to Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

Hej,

I would like to upgrade from Kubuntu 18.10 to the newest version (currently 19.10) but can't find a way.

```
 sudo do-release-upgrade
```

leads to

```
An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'eoan' is not supported with this tool.
```

So I tried to find a way to upgrade to 19.04 first, but couldn't find a way yet.

Does anyone have any idea what I could try next?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Backup first, but I would re-install 19.10 using "Manual" partition (something-else on standard Ubuntu), use your existing partitions and ensure you don't format your system. This will note your added packages, erase system directories (doesn't touch $HOME directories unless you format) installs, then adds-back your additional packages, asks to reboot.  This is far quicker than either of the two upgrades (18.10->19.04, reboot 19.04->19.10) you require but cannot do as @sudodus has stated.  Backup first of course, and ensure you don't have format checked, or follow sudodus' similar route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading between versions of Ubuntu are stepwise:

- Between versions next to each other, in your case from 18.10 to 19.04 and then from 19.04 to 19.10. But 19.04 has passed end of life, so it is not really an option. And even if it were it is a slow and risky path with two steps, likely to fail.
- Between LTS versions, for example from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS. We can expect this upgrade path to be available in August 2020.

---

If you want Ubuntu 19.10, the alternative is a fresh installation, where it is an option to keep the `/home` directory by copying it to a separate 'home' partition and point to it during the installation. This way you can keep settings, that are stored (for example in hidden files and directories) in your home directory, and you data files. But installed programs and global settings must be re-installed and reset.

Comment: @sleepyhead, You write 18.04 in the title but 18.10 in the text. Which version are you running now?

Comment: sorry this was an error. it's about 18.10 to 19.10 like in the description. thanks for pointing that out :)