# Need to Upgrade 18.04 to 19.10

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 19.10

I have tried to upgrade 18.04 to 19.10 using command lines but there is one issue it's showing me is that:

```
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

I have also tried for updates and it's showing `it's up to date`, now what I can do for upgrade my 18.04 Ubuntu to 19.10?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216144/update-from-old-kubuntu-18-10-to-kubuntu-19-10/1216146#1216146)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has two tested & supported upgrade paths. The first was to 18.10 (or the next release), which has closed as it's EOL. The second will be in the future to 20.04, but it'll only open a few days after the release of 20.04.1.  Your intended upgrade path is untested & unsupported by Canonical/Ubuntu, except via re-install as you're missing the 18.10 & 19.04 changes made, and thus outside of what was tested.   What you're asking for contains risks, are you aware of that?

Comment: FYI: What I'd suggest is already in the link provided by @sudodus  (in the comment on the question).   It doesn't directly answer your question/problem, but I personally think what you're asking for is an *unwise* and *riskier* choice (and much slower than re-install either *clean* as per sudodus' answer, or my *dirty* version in comment

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid of **OS reinstalling** and if you use your 18.04 at home, but **not on prod**, than you could experiment with **not supported methods**. But **prepare your Ubuntu installation usb flash drive before**. You could encounter drivers related issues, dependency related issues which will lead you to OS reinstallation.

To update to 19.10, you could try the next:

- remove old, unsupported by 19.10 packages that could be the cause of broken dependencies if you know what are these packages
- move everything from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to some safe place and remove all packages installed from these sources with following `sudo apt autoremove`
- leave at least one desktop manager, one desktop environment, get rid of any additional or big applications that have a lot of dependencies by purging them
- `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
- backup your current `/etc/apt/sources.list` and create the new one:

  ```
  deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted
  deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted
  deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan universe
  deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates universe
  deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan multiverse
  deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates multiverse
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
  ```
- try `do-release-upgrade`

I've [successfully upgraded](https://askubuntu.com/a/1213519/925971) 18.10 in the past, but on the VM and using fresh installed 18.10.

Answer (score 0):

(Recommended) 
Don't update to 19.10 from 18.04
Since, 18.04 is LTS and 19.10 is not. I have already done.
I have seen hell!. It freezes within 3 hours during normal usage.
Nothing works, only option was to hard shut down using power button.
Wait LTS for 19.10 will release in april.